# How do I change which Rails app my local web server points to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost

I've built a very simple Rails App and it worked successfully. localhost:3000/ is pointing there and all is great. However, I am now starting on a new project, and want to see my new project page, which is also pointing to localhost:3000
I have stopped and restarted the rails server, but it still shows me the old project page.

How do I get my new app to show up on the localhost:3000?

Comment: You should start the rails server in the root of your new app. So just change to the new app folder and then type rails s

Comment: If you want to have both apps running at the same time, you can start one with `rails s -p 3001` or any other port number. Then you can access this one on `http://localhost:3001` and the other on `http://localhost:3000`